# Yii2 render view as modal

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal, yii2-basic-app

I want to render view page as a modal for preview

```
<div>
 <?php foreach($softs as $soft) { ?>
  <a id="modalButton" href="<?=Url::to(['documents/view', 'id'=>$soft->id]); ?>"><h3><?=$soft->title; ?></h3></a>
  <?php 
    Modal::begin([
        'header' => 'Test',
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    Modal::end();
    ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

My controller

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Documents::find();
        $softs = $query->where(['type_id' => 2])->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
            'softs' => $softs,
        ]);
    }    

public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->renderAjax('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

My script

```
$(function(){
    $('#modalButton').click(function (){
        $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

But when I click the link it open a viewpage with no CSS, not a pop-up modal.

Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: add one line of code in modal button click function return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You update your code as per below.

```
<div>
 <?php foreach($softs as $soft) { ?>
  <!-- updated id to class here -->
  <a class="modalButton" href="<?=Url::to(['documents/view', 'id'=>$soft->id]); ?>"><h3><?=$soft->title; ?></h3></a>
  <?php } ?>

  <!-- We don't need to print modal popup multiple times -->
  <?php 
    Modal::begin([
        'header' => 'Test',
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    Modal::end();
    ?>

</div>
```

Update  click event.

```
$(function(){
    // changed id to class
    $('.modalButton').click(function (){
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
          $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data)
       });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It works. But only for the first items. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thank you so much.